Blender Terrain Color Mask Convert Texture
How can I eliminate the alpha transition between two colors? I don't want to let other colors appear between transitions.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use four images that are mixed together by alpha, and that final mix into the separate color node before your stencil application. If you set the R G B images to Zero Alpha, you can paint into them toggling between Erase Alpha and Add Alpha. The edges then do not have that weird mix that happens when painting into the same image. You can also see the brush I used is a default Falloff, so you might try a sharper falloff.


Thank you for your valuable time.

You are very welcome; I hope it helps others with the same problem.
